# Find added friend MySQL (Relational)

Tags: php, mysql

Im building a simple social website. I got all friends interaction(eg: send request, approve request) working. So now Im creating a page where you can find all your added friend inside. I built the database relations based on this :

http://www.codedodle.com/2014/12/social-network-friends-database.html

How do I list out my friends?

1st step:

```
SELECT action_user_id, pkusers_rel, user_one_id, user_two_id FROM relationship WHERE (user_one_id = $myuserid OR user_two_id = $myuserid) AND status = $approved
```

2nd step:
Based on the tutorial, user_one_id must be always smaller than user_two_id. So, I use these lines to identify my friend id.

```
if($myuserid == $s["user_one_id"]) {
    $myfriendid = $s["user_two_id"];
} elseif($myuserid == $sb["user_two_id"]) {
    $myfriendid = $s["user_one_id"];
}
```

Now the problem is, how do I find a friend in my friend list?

Im not able to think on the logic here. Finding friend in public is easy, I'd just search the users table. But finding a friend in my own friend list is a problem for me.

Can anyone describe the logic for me? Really appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start use the database.

This should give you a list of friends if you use the correct value for `me`.

```
select user_one_id from relationship where user_two_id = me and status = 1
union
select user_two_id from relationship where user_one_id = me and status = 1;
```

Just from a quick look the ordering of the relationships is not important as you need to find friends with a higher and a lower id than you.`enter code here`

Comment: Thanks for answering Phil, well now let's say I want to find a friend in my friend list with the name "John", I think a JOIN to USERS table should be involved here, right?

Comment: @RedzwanLatif Yes you are right. You would probably have a query that looked up what you wanted and used a where clause to limit the records to this union ... select x, y, z from user where id in (select ... union select ...) and name = 'John';